# Is there a way to allow parallel transaction in GCP Spanner emulator?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-spanner-emulator

I am facing an issue with performance in GCP Spanner emulator (parallel transactions).
It is written that emulator is support only one transaction per time, so other transactions are blocking until the first one will be finished.
Is there any way to bypass it?
Use free trial in GCP is not suitable for me...

I have tried googlign...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation in the emulator is that you can execute at most one transaction **per database** at a time.

You don't write what the use case is that you need to solve/test in this case, but the only possible workaround in the emulator would be to **create two different databases** and execute each transaction on a separate database. Would that work for your specific use case? Would you otherwise mind sharing a little more detail on what it is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I thought about creating two different databases in scope of one emulator but for me it is not use case. My work scope is tests that are working with large amount of data and they are executing for so long and the reason of such performance is transactions limitation. It would be nice to get answer from google why there is such limitation at all.

Comment: I think your answer might be useful for someone but not in my case. If someone knows why there is such limitation, please leave it here))

Comment: Knut is a software engineer in Google, check his profile. :)
As for your use case, I don't think emulator can simulate or repro the scenario you described. It is intended to provide functional parity so dev/test can be done offline. Can it be made to support multiple transactions? Technically, yes. It just wasn't a target scenario. Do create add the feature request if it's valuable to you so the emulator team has it on their radar.